# Update plot with a loop, with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

This code (coming from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33050617/1422096)) works well to do some plot, and update with new plots in a `for` loop:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.axis([-50,50,0,10000])
plt.ion()     # interactive mode on

X = np.arange(-50, 51)
for k in range(1,5):  
    print k 
    Y = [x**k for x in X]
    plt.plot(X, Y)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(1)
```

It works, but it has 2 (minor) drawbacks:

- A warning message:

  > C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py:2399: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Using default event loop until function specific to this GUI is implemented
  >   warnings.warn(str, mplDeprecation)
- If I close the main plot window during the loop, I get:

  > File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 964, in update
  >   self.tk.call('update')
  >   _tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "update" command:  application has been destroyed

**What's the clean way to do non-blocking plots in a `for` loop?**

Comment: It seems specific to maplotlib with Tkinter, might want to add the tag.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with my plot. What I did was, used try..except to avoid that error being shown in the console. It's not the solution but a way to end the program gracefully.

```
    import Tkinter as tk

    while plt.get_fignums():
        try:
            plt.pause(0.2);
        except tk.TclError:
            break;
```