# A Matplotlib figure loop which plots and waits for raw_input

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm have a looping script which plots (`matplotlib`) and then, after plotting, waits for `raw_input` before continuing. This would allow me to delete any figures I don't want/need before the loop continues.

I have tried a few different ways but they never seem to properly display the figures before continuing.

```
# test1
x = [1, 2, 3]
plt.ion() # turn on interactive mode
for loop in range(0,3):
    y = np.dot(x, loop)
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()
    _ = raw_input("Press [enter] to continue.")
```

^ This one plots the figure windows but shows nothing until the loop has ended

```
#test2
x = [1, 2, 3]
plt.ion() # turn on interactive mode
for loop in range(0,3):
    y = np.dot(x, loop)
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.pause(0.02)
    plt.show()
    _ = raw_input("Press [enter] to continue.")
```

^ This one plots the figures fine but then freezes and the figure window crashes when the raw_input opens. The windows return to normal (are usable and zoomable) again once the full loop has finished

I've looked into the `plt.show(block=False)` command but haven't had any progress

Any ideas?

N.b. This question is very similar to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269157/plotting-in-a-non-blocking-way-with-matplotlib) but, as you can see from the examples above, I haven't managed to get it working using those answers (which suggested `plt.ion()` and `plt.pause(0.2)`

Comment: Have you tried plt.draw() instead?

Comment: Heya @hashcode55, just tried that (replacing `plt.show()` with `plt.draw()`) and it produces the same result as test2

Comment: I know how to make this work. I had the same issue, and solved it with a matplotlib TimedAnimation. I could get the graph updating fluently when new data arrives. I don't have time right now, but I can explain the details tomorrow.

Comment: @mjp its kinda weird as the code without even replacing `plt.show()` is working perfectly on my machine.

Comment: @hashcode55 as in you can see the figures and interect with them without them crashing, before you press enter to continue the loop? I have cleared everything and restarted the terminal a number of times. Not sure what could  be the issue.

Comment: Yup working totally fine, which `matplotlib` version are you using?

Comment: Backend is TkAgg and the version is 1.5.1

Answer (score 0):

As you almost discovered, plt.pause(interval) does actually work, because, according to the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pause.html),

> If there is an active figure, it will be updated and displayed before
>   the pause, and the GUI event loop (if any) will run during the pause.

So if you had increased your pause interval to the following:

```
interval = 10 # units of seconds
plt.pause(interval)
plt.show()
input("Press Enter to continue...")
```

- You would be able to interact with the plot during that interval.
- Once the pause ends and waits for an input, you can no longer
  interact with the plot.
- The plot probably crashed because you interacted with the plot after
  the pause while the program was waiting for raw_input(), which by the
  way has been changed to input() in Python 3.x and may also help
  prevent the figure window from crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that you can try is something like this... Here you do incude pauses, but you can interrupt them as you wish :)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# This gives a total of 30 seconds pause.. which can be interrupted
n_pauses = 3
pause_interval = 10

plt.plot(your_array)
for _ in range(n_pauses):
    try:
        plt.pause(pause_interval)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

x = input('Enter your input...')
```