# Dynamically plot, show, and close changing data sizes in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I need to plot, and show a matplotlib graph that updates dynamically. Problem is, my data size is always growing by one. I'm ok replotting the whole thing, but I need the plot to be visible until the next one is available. As far as I can tell, because my data shape is changing, I can't use plt.ion()

Here's what I have.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


while inputs != outputs:
    percent_complete = inputs/outputs      #Total number of input files completed
    y = np.append(y, percent_complete)
    plt.plot(np.arange(len(y)), y)
    time.sleep(10)
    update(inputs)               #This function counts the number of inputs have complete
    plt.close()
```

So the problem with this is that the entire program waits for you to manually close the plot before continuing. Is there a way to visualize the plot, continue running the program, close the plot and open a new updated one?

Also, I needs to work across platform. I thought about adding an os open file statement, but that would need to be os specific.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out, due to help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269157/plotting-in-a-non-blocking-way-with-matplotlib) answer, though I am still getting a deprecated matplotlib answer.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.ion()
while inputs != outputs:
    percent_complete = inputs/outputs      #Total number of input files completed
    y = np.append(y, percent_complete)
    plt.plot(np.arange(len(y)), y)
    plt.pause(.001)
    time.sleep(10)
    update(inputs)               #This function counts the number of inputs have complete
    plt.close()
```

Not sure I understand why adding in the plt.pause(.001) solves this, but it works.