# Non-blocking Matplotlib Animation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to run a FuncAnimation concurrently to my main program, unfortunately, it's blocking the execution of `MainProgram` whatever I do.

I've tried:

1. `plt.show(block=False)` program continues but plot shows blank
2. Returning the animation and storing in a variable - `MainProgram` is blocked
3. Both: `MainProgram` runs but plot window is blank

I am aware of this question, however, I assume that given the use of Animation the solutions presented aren't appropriate.

[Plotting in a non-blocking way with Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269157/plotting-in-a-non-blocking-way-with-matplotlib)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
import time

def runGraph():
    # Parameters
    x_len = 200         # Number of points to display
    y_range = [10, 40]  # Range of possible Y values to display

    # Create figure for plotting
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    xs = list(range(0, 200))
    ys = [0] * x_len
    ax.set_ylim(y_range)

    # Create a blank line. We will update the line in animate
    line, = ax.plot(xs, ys)

    # Add labels
    plt.title('TMP102 Temperature over Time')
    plt.xlabel('Samples')
    plt.ylabel('Temperature (deg C)')

    # This function is called periodically from FuncAnimation
    def animate(i, ys):

        # Read temperature (Celsius) from TMP102
        temp_c = np.random.random(1)*40

        # Add y to list
        ys.append(temp_c)

        # Limit y list to set number of items
        ys = ys[-x_len:]

        # Update line with new Y values
        line.set_ydata(ys)

        return line,

    # Set up plot to call animate() function periodically
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,
        animate,
        fargs=(ys,),
        interval=50,
        blit=True)
    plt.show()

def MainProgram():
     while 1:
         print('Main program')
         time.sleep(0.5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runGraph()
    MainProgram()
```

Comment: try first using `plt.ion()` at the beginning of your code, then replace your `plt.show()` 
 for `plt.pause(0.01)`

Comment: The plot just shows as a black screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting in a non-blocking way with Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269157/plotting-in-a-non-blocking-way-with-matplotlib)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most generic way to solve this is by using the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html) module.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from multiprocessing import Process
import numpy as np
import time

def runGraph():
    # Parameters
    print('show')
    x_len = 200         # Number of points to display
    y_range = [10, 40]  # Range of possible Y values to display

    # Create figure for plotting
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    xs = list(range(0, 200))
    ys = [0] * x_len
    ax.set_ylim(y_range)

    # Create a blank line. We will update the line in animate
    line, = ax.plot(xs, ys)

    # Add labels
    plt.title('TMP102 Temperature over Time')
    plt.xlabel('Samples')
    plt.ylabel('Temperature (deg C)')

    # This function is called periodically from FuncAnimation
    def animate(i, ys):

        # Read temperature (Celsius) from TMP102
        temp_c = np.random.random(1)*40

        # Add y to list
        ys.append(temp_c)

        # Limit y list to set number of items
        ys = ys[-x_len:]

        # Update line with new Y values
        line.set_ydata(ys)

        return line,


    # Set up plot to call animate() function periodically

    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,
        animate,
        fargs=(ys,),
        interval=50,
        blit=True)
    plt.show()



def MainProgram():
     while 1:
         print('Main program')
         time.sleep(0.5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=runGraph)
    p.start()
    MainProgram()
    p.join()
```

Comment: Very helpful example, thank you. I ran into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67183501/setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence-requested-array-has-an-inhomogeneous-sh) issue with `numpy`. SInce it's only used for the temperature simulator, I just did `import random` and changed to `temp_c = random.random()*40` to fix it.