# matplotlib.close() does not close plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Python 3.6 in jupyter notebook. plt.close does not close plot. I tried with plt.ion() also and many other ways.

I want to display image, then wait for pause or input() and then remove the previous image and show the new one.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import sleep
from scipy import eye

plt.imshow(eye(3))
plt.show()
sleep(1)
plt.close()
```

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269157/plotting-in-a-non-blocking-way-with-matplotlib). Your script is pauses when you call `plt.show()`, which means that nothing else can happen before you close the figure manually.

Comment: @ThomasKühn when I'm adding plt.close() to example u gave to me, it does not change smth.

Comment: The point was not to leave out `plt.show()`, the point was that `plt.show()` *blocks* the script. You could use non-blocking mode, i.e. `plt.show(block=True)`, but you should be aware how that changes the functionality of matplotlib, hence the link. If you *do* use non-blocking mode, you will need some other measure of keeping the script alive ...

Comment: @ThomasKühn I can display images after pauses or inputs. But these images all are on my input canvas. I wish to display only one image which is the last in that action sequence. So: the pause happened, the last image displayed, next pause happened, that image removed and displayed a new one.

Comment: I answered before reading the comments, I fear that what OP wants is something entirely different than what the question asks for. @Nikytee can you please clarify inside the question what *exactly*  you are trying to achieve?

Comment: So I think what OP wants is to get rid of the figure that is produced in the output section of a jupyter notebook and replace it with a new figure repeatedly (probably using the inline backend). Is that correct?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that shows a sequence of plots, each for one second. Essential are the commants `plt.show(block = False)` and `plt.pause(1)` instead of `sleep(1)`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def show_image(n):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
    y = x**n
    ax.plot(x,y, label = 'x**{}'.format(n))
    ax.legend()
    plt.show(block=False)
    plt.pause(1)
    plt.close(fig)



for i in range(10):
    show_image(i)
```

Comment: I replaced plt.pause(1) on sleep(1) due an error "name 'time' is not defined".
But figures still do not close. Sry, I dont know whats going on. Maybe I will check versions of matplotlib.

Comment: @Nikytee did you try to run the example I posted? It works perfectly for me.

Comment: Yes. Except "plt.pause(1)" string which I replaced due to the mistake.

Comment: I updated libraries and there is no "name 'time' is not defined" error now. But figures from your code still do not close.

Comment: @Nikytee ok, then this must be special in jupyter notebook. I unfortunately don't have any experience with that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you want is to show a plot, wait 1 second, then let it close automatically.

This would be achieved as follows.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import eye

plt.imshow(eye(3))

def show_and_close(sec):
    timer = plt.gcf().canvas.new_timer(interval=sec*1000)
    timer.add_callback(lambda : plt.close())
    timer.single_shot = True
    timer.start()
    plt.show()

show_and_close(1)
```

Comment: Ty, but the plot does not disappear(