# Plotting multiple figures in a loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, pycharm

I am trying to plot a diagram inside a loop and I expect to get two separate figures, but Python only shows one figure instead. In fact, it seems Python plots the second figure over the first one. This is the code I am using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0,10)
y = np.arange(0,10)

for _ in range(2):
   plt.plot(x,y)
   plt.show()
```

It worth noting that I am working with Python 2.7 in PyCharm environment. Any kind of advice is appreciated.

Comment: Look into the `subplots` figure constructor: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269157/plotting-in-a-non-blocking-way-with-matplotlib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0,10)
y = np.arange(0,10)

for _ in range(2):
   plt.figure() # add this statement before your plot
   plt.plot(x,y)
   plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

This could do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0,10)
y = np.arange(0,10)

f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax2.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```