# matplotlib.show(block=False) shows a blank window when used from Python.NET

Tags: python, matplotlib, python.net

Does anyone know how to let matplotlib (V3.3.0) to show a figure and then continue executing the rest of the Python script when executed from Python.NET PythoneEngine.Exec(script) in a C# app?

```
plt.show(block=False)
```

This works as expected.

When I run the same script directly from Python interpreter V3.8.4 (64 bit) it works. So, I think that all the libraries are installed correctly. I'm using the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PythonEngine.Initialize();

        using (Py.GIL())
        {
            var script = "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt\n"
                         + "import numpy as np\n"
                         + "x = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)\n"
                         + "y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * x)\n"
                         + "fig, ax = plt.subplots()\n"
                         + "ax.plot(x, y)\n"
                         + "plt.show(block=False)\n";
            PythonEngine.Exec(script);
        }
        
        Console.ReadLine();
        PythonEngine.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

This shows a blank window when PythoneEngine.Exec() finishes. The figure window itself is unresponsive.
If I remove `block=False` from the `plt.show(block=False)`, then it shows the sine curve correctly. But I have to close the figure window to let it continue.

I'm using .NET Framework 4.8 on Windows 10 (64 bit).

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `PythonEngine.BeginAllowThreads()` to initialize Python threading support: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki/Threading

Comment: I added it between Inititalize() and GIL(). But it made no difference. I dug through matplotlib source code and the last statement in show(block=False) is "yield". I'm wondering if it's not working with Python.NET?

Comment: Hm. Maybe the issue is not with Python.NET: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269157/plotting-in-a-non-blocking-way-with-matplotlib

Comment: I saw the SO. I tried ion() and pause(). Nothing works. Because my code works when executed from Python interpreter, I still think that the issue can be in Python.NET.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue of the blank window. But the solution requires the message pump, which is an infinite loop, after `PythonEngine.Exec(script)`. In that sense, it does not behave like the real Python interpreter that shows the ">>>" prompt right after the `plt.show(block=False)` is executed.

Still, I want to leave the code here for anyone who happens to come across this SO question.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PythonEngine.Initialize();
    dynamic root;
    using (Py.GIL())
    {
        var script = "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt\n"
                     + "import numpy as np\n"
                     + "x = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)\n"
                     + "y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * x)\n"
                     + "fig, ax = plt.subplots()\n"
                     + "ax.plot(x, y)\n"
                     + "plt.show(block=False)\n";
        PythonEngine.Exec(script);
        dynamic pyplt = Py.Import("matplotlib.pyplot");
        root = pyplt.figure().canvas.manager.window;
    }

    while (true)
    {
        using (Py.GIL())
        {
            root.update_idletasks();
            root.update();
        }

        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
}
```

My actual application is a WPF app, rather than the console, and needs to show multiple matplotlib windows. I will still need to manage the thread such that only a single thread is used to run the script. Otherwise, a PythonException with "RuntimeError : main thread is not in main loop" message is thrown deep inside matplotlib call chain when `PythonEngine.Exec(script)` is executed for the second time (to show the second matplotlib window).

Comment: Hi, I am using the same process which you are doing but we are using Html and .net API. So we don't have WPF. How can we plot the matplotlib chart in HTML? I am searching for this scenario for so many days. Could you please help me to solve this issue