# Previously working python script now stops halfway through

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I've been working on a python script to do Probit analysis to find the Lower Limit of Detection (LLoD) for assays run in our lab. I had a script that worked perfectly last week, but was messy and lacked any kind of input-checking to make sure the user's input was valid.

On running the script, the user was prompted for a few questions (the column headers for the relevant data in the .csv file containing the data to analyze, and whether or not to use the data in said columns as-is or in log_10 form). The script would then
-perform the necessary data cleanup and calculations
-print out a table of the relevant data along with the equation and R^2 value for the linear regression
-display a graph of the data along with the linear regression and calculated LLoD
-print out "The lower limit of detection at 95% CI is [whatever]".

Now, on running the script, the program stops after printing the data table and displaying the graph (the regression equation and R^2 value are not printed, nor is anything afterwards). Furthermore, python doesn't return to prompt for input with the standard `>>>`, and I have to exit and reopen Python. Does anyone have any idea what's going on? Full code at the bottom of post, sample data can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1skDc-ko0V-dePBMc3EIqVLUqSv_M_D5M/view?usp=sharing). Note: This is the exact data I've been using, which was working last week.

(P.S. any misc. tips for cleaning up the code would be appreciated as well, so long as the function is unchanged. I come from a C background and adapting to Python is still a work in progress...)

Code: (FWIW I'm running 3.8)

```
import os
import math
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy
from scipy.stats import norm
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *

# Initialize tkinter
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

# Prompt user for data file and column headers, ask whether to use log(qty)
print("In the directory prompt, select the .csv file containing data for analysis")
path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
#data = pd.read_csv(path, usecols=[conc, detect])
data = pd.read_csv(path)


while True:
    conc = input("Enter the column header for concentration/number of copies: ")
    if conc in data.columns:
        break
    else:
        print('Invalid input. Column \''+str(conc)+'\' does not exist. Try again')
        continue

while True:
    detect = input("Enter the column header for target detection: ")
    if detect in data.columns:
        break
    else:
        print('Invalid input. Column \''+str(detect)+'\' does not exist. Try again')
        continue

while True:
    logans = input("Analyze using log10(concentration/number of copies)? (y/n): ")
    if logans == 'y':
        break
    elif logans == 'n':
        break
    else:
        print('Invalid input. Please enter either y or n.')
        continue

# Read the columns of data specified by the user and rename them for consistency
data = data.rename(columns={conc:"qty", detect:"result"})

# Create list of unique values for RNA quantity, initialize vectors of same length
# to store probabilies and probit scores for each
qtys = data['qty'].unique()
log_qtys = [0] * len(qtys)
prop = [0] * len(qtys)
probit = [0] * len(qtys)

# Function to get the hitrate/probability of detection for a given quantity
# Note: any values in df.result that cannot be parsed as a number will be converted to NaN
def hitrate(qty, df):
    t_s = df[df.qty == qty].result
    t_s = t_s.apply(pd.to_numeric, args=('coerce',)).isna()
    return (len(t_s)-t_s.sum())/len(t_s)

# Iterate over quantities to calculate log10(quantity), the corresponding probability
# of detection, and its associated probit score
for idx, val in enumerate(qtys):
    log_qtys[idx] = math.log10(val)
    prop[idx] = hitrate(val, data)
    probit[idx] = 5 + norm.ppf(prop[idx])

# Create a dataframe (with headers) composed of the quantaties and their associated
# probabilities and probit scores, then drop rows with probability of 0 or 1
hitTable = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([qtys,log_qtys,prop,probit]).T, columns=['qty','log_qty','probability','probit'])
hitTable.probit.replace([np.inf,-np.inf],np.nan, inplace=True)
hitTable.dropna(inplace=True)

def regPlot(x, y, log):
    # Update parameters, set y95 to probit score corresponding to 95% CI
    params = {'mathtext.default': 'regular'}
    plt.rcParams.update(params)
    y95 = 6.6448536269514722

    # Define lambda function for a line, run regression, and find the coefficient of determination
    regFun = lambda m, x, b : (m*x) + b
    regression = scipy.stats.linregress(x,y)
    r_2 = regression.rvalue*regression.rvalue

    # Solve y=mx+b for x at 95% CI
    log_llod = (y95 - regression.intercept) / regression.slope
    xmax = log_llod * 1.2

    # Start plotting all the things!
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_ylabel('Probit score\n$(\sigma + 5)$')

    if log == 'y':
        ax.set_xlabel('$log_{10}$(input quantity)')

    elif log == 'n':
        ax.set_xlabel('input quantity')

    else:
        raise ValueError('Error when calling regPlot(x,y,log) - User input invalid.')

    x_r = [0, xmax]
    y_r = [regression.intercept, regFun(regression.slope,x_r[1],regression.intercept)]
    ax.plot(x_r, y_r, '--k') # linear regression
    ax.plot(log_llod, y95, color='red', marker='o', markersize=8) # LLOD point
    ax.plot([0,xmax], [y95,y95], color='red', linestyle=':') # horiz. red line
    ax.plot([log_llod,log_llod], [regFun(regression.slope,x_r[0],regression.intercept),7.1], color='red', linestyle=':') # vert. red line
    ax.plot(x, y, 'bx') # actual (qty, probit) data points
    ax.grid() # grid
    plt.show()
    print('\n Linear regression using least-squares method yields:\n')
    print('\t\ty = '+str("%.3f"%regression.slope)+'x + '+str("%.3f"%regression.intercept)+'\n')
    print('\twith a corresponding R-squared value of', str("%.5f"%r_2)+"\n")

    return regression.slope, regression.intercept, r_2, regression.stderr, regression.intercept_stderr, log_llod

print('\n', hitTable, '\n')

if logans == 'y':
    m, b, r_2, stderr, int_stderr, log_llod = regPlot(hitTable.log_qty, hitTable.probit, logans)
    llod_95 = 10**log_llod
    if r_2 < 0.9:
        print('WARNING: low r-squared value for linear regression. Try re-analyzing without using log10.')

elif logans == 'n':
    m, b, r_2, stderr, int_stderr, log_llod = regPlot(hitTable.qty, hitTable.probit, logans)
    llod_95 = log_llod
    if r_2 < 0.9:
        print('WARNING: low r-squared value for linear regression. Try re-analyzing using log10.')

else:
    raise ValueError('Error when attempting to evaluate llod_95 - User input invalid.')

print("\nThe lower limit of detection (LLoD) at 95% CI is " + str("%.4f"%llod_95) + ".\n")
```

Comment: I have stylistic comments.  Ignore if you choose.  You don't need the `else:` or the `continue` in your `while` loops.  If you pass the `if`s, then validation has failed.  Remember you can use either double or single quotes for strings; this reads easier: `print(f"Invalid input. Column '{conc}' does not exist.  Try again.")`

Comment: Ah, you're right, that does read a lot more cleanly! Thanks! Dynamic typing is hard for me to get used to, so I've developed the bad habit of explicitly type-casting variables even when I have no expectation that a variable will be anything other than ex. a string. Could you elaborate on not needing `else:`? Are you saying `while True: conc=(get input); if conc in data: break; print(error message)` will loop back to prompting for input if the input is invalid without the need for continue? (Hopefully you can understand my improvised formatting)

Comment: Yes, that's right.  If you pass through the `if`, then the validation has failed, so flowing out the bottom the loop will cause it to cycle again.  If you find the repetitive code ugly, then just write a function to handle it.  Pass your prompt and your "failed validation" message.

Comment: Followup while I'm picking your brain: is there a way to consolidate the `while` loops for each input question? It felt/looked ugly writing one for each question, but I wasn't sure how to condense them into one `while True:` block. Something like having `detect = ((get input))` immediately after `conc =((get input))`, then something along the lines of `if (conc in data) && (detect in data): break`...

Comment: Sorry had to delete my previous comment cause editing timed out. There's no way to check two conditions in an if statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like it's because of i/o blocking when `plt.show()` is called. It displays the graph in a window and waits for you to close it before continuing with the code execution.

This is by default in `matplotlib` but you can make it non-blocking:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33050617/15332448

Comment: Weird. Even after closing the plot, nothing happens. And I'm still not sure why it'd have no issues last Friday but suddenly lock up today. The only changes I've made in between are at the very beginning - the previous version didn't check whether the user input column names actually existed. Everything below `data = data.rename(columns={conc:"qty",detect:"result...` is completely untouched

Comment: You could try running your code in VSCode or JuputerLab where you can inspect the variables. I've just tried the code with your data and noticed that two 'qty' columns can be created (if 'qty' is not one of the chosen columns in the beginning) in `data` which I don't think is expected. As for some style tips, for user input and validation, I would look into using `argparse` so that you can use command line arguments.

Comment: Odd, 'qty' isn't duplicated on my end. Even with a different dataset (that has "conc" instead of "qty" as the column header) found here --> https://drive.google.com/file/d/14TCFA5IlwwDeoRM7Jy7D1rDCYqkIIrUq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: In that csv, there's no 'qty' column so it doesn't happen. But in the original csv there is, and then there's a creation of an additional 'qty' column when doing the rename which led to some errors for me.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Thanks for pointing this out. In practice, the columns will never be called "qty" or "result", I manually renamed them for ease of testing (cf. typing "sgE TAL-E copies/mL" each time), but this is still a good catch. Thanks!