# After updating Pycharm charts are no showing up no more

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pycharm

After updating pycharm, my charts are not showing up anymore. Before, without even importing `matplotplib`, i would be able to use pandas.plot() and charts where showing up directly.

Now, the only way I can manage to see charts is to to this :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

but this is very annoying since I can't use my console until I close the chart which I could do before updating pycharm.

reading [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886625/pycharm-does-not-show-plot)  I hoped that `plt.interactive(False)` would fix this but it doesnt.

my backend is:

```
matplotlib.get_backend()
Out[19]: 
'Qt5Agg'
```

any idea? thanks for any help.

Comment: possible to use IDLE instead of pycharm?