# Plot doesn't show in PyCharm but shows in Terminal in OSX terminal

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, pycharm, anaconda

My code draws a plot in Terminal in OSX El Capitan but not in PyCharm. Both Terminal and PyCharm interpreters are set to Anaconda Python 3.6.2 and have the necessary packages all installed.

```
def plot_data(samples, centroids, clusters=None):
    """
    Plot samples and color it according to cluster centroid.
    :param samples: samples that need to be plotted.
    :param centroids: cluster centroids.
    :param clusters: list of clusters corresponding to each sample.
    """

    colors = ['blue', 'green', 'gold']
    assert centroids is not None

    if clusters is not None:
        sub_samples = []
        for cluster_id in range(centroids[0].shape[0]):
            sub_samples.append(np.array([samples[i] for i in range(samples.shape[0]) if clusters[i] == cluster_id]))
    else:
        sub_samples = [samples]

    plt.figure(figsize=(7, 5))

    for clustered_samples in sub_samples:
        cluster_id = sub_samples.index(clustered_samples)
        #print(cluster_id)
        #print(clustered_samples[:,0])
        #print(clustered_samples[:,1])
        plt.plot(clustered_samples[:, 0], clustered_samples[:, 1], 'o', color=colors[cluster_id], alpha=0.75,
                 label='Data Points: Cluster %d' % cluster_id)

    plt.xlabel('x1', fontsize=14)
    plt.ylabel('x2', fontsize=14)
    plt.title('Plot of X Points', fontsize=16)
    plt.grid(True)

    # Drawing a history of centroid movement
    tempx, tempy = [], []
    for mycentroid in centroids:
        tempx.append(mycentroid[:, 0])
        tempy.append(mycentroid[:, 1])

    for cluster_id in range(len(tempx[0])):
        plt.plot(tempx, tempy, 'rx--', markersize=8)

    plt.legend(loc=4, framealpha=0.5)

    plt.show(block=True)
```

Also, I tried the solutions in [Pycharm does not show plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886625/pycharm-does-not-show-plot) and none of them really worked. For example, adding the following lines after `plt.show(block=True)` didn't solve the problem.

```
matplotlib.get_backend()
plt.interactive(False)
plt.figure()
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered pretty much the same irritance, and had also tried the other solutions mentioned everywhere for matplotlib/etc. Seeing as Terminal (aka, regular python/ipython) runs these plots, I figured that there must be a workaround in PyCharm to run a pure console that would avoid the buggy overhead. Well, following the first [answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709105/does-pycharm-have-interactive-python-interpreter) advice I found, you can simply access the Python Console that is in PyCharm, and it outputs plots normally.

Comment: Should this be brought up to the attention of Python community? In that specific case, I ended up using my Windows 7 machine as I had to use PyCharm.

Comment: I am no expert on the matter yet, but it does seem a major bug that isn't being addressed in an adequately rigorous fashion, based on the different forums I've searched to find a solution.