# Python matplotlib no graph output

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new in Python. I am trying to learn by watching youtube videos or other online tutorials. [image]

When I did a similar code in Pycharm I see the following:-

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
cars = pd.read_csv("./cars.csv")
cars = cars.rename( columns={'Unnamed: 0':'model'})
print("car:\n",cars)
y1 = cars['hp']
x = range(32)
print(plt.plot(x,y1))
```

Output:-

```
car:
                   model   mpg  cyl   disp   hp  ...  vs  am  gear  carb  2am
0             Mazda RX4  21.0    6  160.0  110  ...   0   1     4     4    2
1         Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0    6  160.0  110  ...   0   1     4     4    2
2            Datsun 710  22.8    4  108.0   93  ...   1   1     4     1    2
3        Hornet 4 Drive  21.4    6  258.0  110  ...   1   0     3     1    0
.....
31           Volvo 142E  21.4    4  121.0  109  ...   1   1     4     2    2
[32 rows x 13 columns]
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7ff689975240>]
```

I trucked output from 1 to 31. My confusion why I don't see the graph as it is shown in the video. What is missing or what is wrong?

Comment: in that tutorial anaconda platform. I guess it doesn't require print. For me, if I don't add print anything is printed in the console.

Comment: check my edit. You also need to add `plt.show()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pycharm does not show plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886625/pycharm-does-not-show-plot)

Comment: @Georgy The accepted answer `plt.show()` it doesn't help me.

Comment: @masiboo Have you tried other answers as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in the second case you are printing the `plt.plot`. Just remove the `print` command and also add `plt.show()`. The first editor is called Jupyter Notebook where you activate the inline plotting by using `%matplotlib inline`.

```
 plt.plot(x, y1) 
 plt.show()
```

Comment: in that tutorial anaconda platform. I guess it doesn't require print in anaconda. For me, if I don't add print anything is printed in the console.

Comment: Now I got this: UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
  plt.show()

Comment: I can't use %matplotlib inline in PyCharm. how do I do it in Pycharm?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are just using Pandas in this way.

It should be like:

```
y1 = cars['hp']
x = range(32)
plt.plot(x,y1) # plots the data
plt.show() # shows the graph
```

You can also add more details such as:

```
plt.xlabel() # name of x line
plt.ylabel() # name of y line
plt.title()
plt.legend(loc='upper left') # place of the legend
plt.grid() # adds grid
```

etc.

Comment: I had to update code because of warning `plt.xticks()
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.title("title")
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.grid()`  this warning No handles with labels found to put in legend. No graph output.

Comment: You should add labels in plt.plot(x, y1) part, within the parantheses, like: plt.plot(x, y1, label='something')

Comment: I wrote the second paragrahp just as an example, you don't have to use them to plot the graph. Sorry for the confusion.